# what do these options affect?

Tags: world

[image]

Because I wanted to know effect of options of world tab in properties editor, I set each color option as green, red, blue. Rendering image showed me only 'surface' option being meaningful. I want to know where I can see red(volume) and blue(viewport display) color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The viewport display only displays in the 3D viewport. The surface and volume panels actually provide shortcuts to edit the world nodes, which you can also examine in the shader editor, when you set it to *World*.

### Surface

The surface color of the world when rendering. This color will be visible in the background when rendering and will indirectly light objects. You can see the indirect lighting on the left face of the cube. To enter rendered mode, press <kbd>Z</kbd> in the 3D Viewport and choose *Rendered*.

[image: surface]

### Viewport Display

The surface color of the world when using the workbench renderer. This color will be visible in the background when not in rendered mode and will not indirectly light objects. You will only see this color in the background in solid or wireframe mode.
You will also have to enable its display in the *Viewport Shading* settings.
To enter solid mode, press <kbd>Z</kbd> in the 3D Viewport and choose *Solid*.

[image: viewport display]

### Volume

You have select a Background BSDF in the Surface Panel which gets connected to the world output Surface. You will have to select a fitting Volumetric BSDF in the volume panel, since it will get connected to the volume output. A **volume scatter** BSDF scatters light volumetrically.

[image: volume]

Comment: thank you for good answer. have a nice weekend.